# Problems when Routing Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have `RoutePrefix` above in my controller like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Catalogos")]
```

And I have method like:

```
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
     //some code there
}
```

So when I use postman and send route like:

```
http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogos/
```

It runs without problems. The issue starts when I try to do another method like:

```
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[Route("GetCatalogo")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCatalogoPadre(HttpRequestMessage request, string catalogo)
{
      //some code there
}
```

So I try in postman url like:

```
http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogos/GetCatalogo/
```

But I get:

> {   "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>   URI 'http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogos/GetCatalogo/'.",
>   "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Catalogos'
>   that matches the name 'GetCatalogo'." }

Why I can´t route it? I don´t understand what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is most likely that you are routing via convention.

Make sure that attribute routing is enabled.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And in your controller make sure that the routes have been properly configured.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Catalogos")]
public class CatalogosController : ApiController {

    [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Matches GET api/Catalogos
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
         HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
         //some code there
    }

    [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCatalogo")] //Matches GET api/Catalogos/GetCatalogo
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCatalogoPadre(string catalogo) {
          HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
          //some code there
    }

}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: I have it exactly as you comment, but I still can´t hit method

Comment: Something extrange, other controllers accept route, I don´t have any problems to execute them. There are any special config to hit route then whenApiConfig?